# Close gap smoothly when one div in a row gets hidden

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a grid of divs next to each other, lets say each 200x200 pixels in rows and columns (inline-block). Now I use jquery to fade out one div by clicking on it. Normally the now resulting gap is filled by the other divs by a simple "jump".

Is it possible to avoid the jump and smoothly drift the divs **from one row to another**?

Comment: Yes it is but you have to "collapse" the fading div smoothly (by manipulating dimensions0 and then, at the end, hiding it completely. Just using opacity won't do it.

Comment: As I described, it is not about how to hide the DIV smoothly, but to close the gap smoothly by the remaining DIVS from all existing rows beneath.

Comment: Which is my point...the gap can't close smoothly unless the element is collapsed. Of course, a subsequent element changing rows is a lot more complicated. There is NO animation that can manage that. You'd need a LOT of JS to figure out positioning etc.

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this, just replace the setTimeout with your click event.

[Here is a working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/et1Lsdua/3/).

```js
setTimeout(function(){
 $("#boxToHide").addClass('hideMe');
  
}, 3000);
```

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.box{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  transition: 1s;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 10px;
}
.hideMe{
  animation: hide 1s forwards;
  
}
@keyframes hide{
  0% {opacity: 1; width: 200px;}
  10%{opacity: 0; width: 200px;}
  99%{opacity: 0; width: 0;}
  100% {opacity: 0; width:0; display:none}
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div id="boxToHide" class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works for a single row, yes. But if you have more DIVs, the ones going up to close the gap, do not move smoothly. See: https://jsfiddle.net/6ru0jk5b/

Comment: It still closes the gap smoothly, at one point the following box simply realizes that it has enough space to be shown on the upper row. If you also want every row to move to the left, you'd have to generate transparent placeholders to the front of each line which is using the same animation as the clicked box.